# Java Programming Basic Math

Tags: java, math

I want to multiply string data with 0.99. The data I want to multiply is from combo boxes.

My question is how do you do it with my code?

```
class JComboBoxListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e)
    {
        String price = "0.99";

        string1 = (String)
        cboCoke.getSelectedItem();
        string2 = (String)
        cboSprite.getSelectedItem();
        string3 = (String)
        cboOrange.getSelectedItem();
        string4 = (String)
        cboRoot.getSelectedItem();

        drinkTotal = string1 + string2 + string3 + string4 * price;



        lblbevPrice.setText(df.format(drinkTotal));
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using, and what effect do you expect from multiplying a string by another string?

Comment: Retagged. This is not eclipse specific and deal with math.

Comment: @user1251138 If any of the answers helped, could you please select a best answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a quantity (integer) that you're multiplying by a price? In which case you should use

```
Integer.parseInt(string1) + Integer.parseInt(string2) ...
```

if they're doubles rather than integers, you could use

```
Double.parseDouble(string1) + Double.parseDouble(string2) + ...
```

Comment: It's `Integer.parseInt()`. When you fix that, tag me with @Ryan and I'll give you +1.

Comment: Excellent. Best answer so far, then :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Double.parseDouble() to convert string to double.

So, for example,

```
   double value1 = Double.parseDouble(string1); // gets the first string as a double.
```

Now, do the rest similarly.

After you have done all the computations, use the Double.toString() method to convert the double back into a String.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Double.parseDouble(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) to convert the contents of your strings into double-precision floating-point numbers.